# Generic method's typing with generic type as a parameter does not work properly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following code:

```js
class Events<T extends object> {
    raiseEvent<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
        // do something here
    }
}

interface EventsDictionary {
    somethingHappened: number
    whatever: string
}

interface AdditionalEvents {
    disconnnected: CloseEvent
}

type AddAdditional<T extends object> = Omit<T, keyof AdditionalEvents> & AdditionalEvents

const events = new Events<AddAdditional<EventsDictionary>>()
events.raiseEvent("disconnnected", new CloseEvent("..."))  // works fine
```

Now if we use this class in another class that is also generic like this:

```js
class SomeOtherClass<Something extends object> {
    constructor() {
        const events = new Events<AddAdditional<Something>>()
        events.raiseEvent("disconnnected", new CloseEvent("...")) 
        //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // Argument of type 'CloseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Something["connnected"] & CloseEvent'.
        //  Type 'CloseEvent' is not assignable to type 'Something["connnected"]'.ts(2345)
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to work around this problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of the type `AddAdditional` ?

Answer (score 0):

The generic parameter isn't speciefied enough, Something needs to extends the `AditionnalEvents`

```
class SomeOtherClass<Something extends AdditionalEvents> {
    constructor() {
        const events = new Events<AddAdditional<Something>>()
        events.raiseEvent("disconnnected", new CloseEvent("...")) 
    }
}
```

Also to me, your `AddAdditional` type is weird. Should it be a union like following ?

```
class Events<T extends object> {
    raiseEvent<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) {
        // do something here
    }
}

interface EventsDictionary {
    somethingHappened: number
    whatever: string
}

interface AdditionalEvents {
    disconnnected: CloseEvent
}

const events = new Events<EventsDictionary & AdditionalEvents>()
events.raiseEvent("disconnnected", new CloseEvent("..."))  // works fine


class SomeOtherClass<Something extends AdditionalEvents> {
    constructor() {
        const events = new Events<Something & AdditionalEvents>()
        events.raiseEvent("disconnnected", new CloseEvent("...")) 
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBuBTAdgFwgHgCrUQD1RQBMYB7AIwCtFhUA%20aAbwCho3oAnMASwkQRSoMAaVwFiMANaIAnqQBm0LHQAU0mQC5owgDTR4YEAFdEWrAG1hAXQCUTVu0cB6J9CKloEUgFtEqABbcyADm0P6IHIgObAC%20zHHMQYQc8mDAiHBIaBAAIty03KTIYBwy9o5evgFBwQASYAAODSiIRFrIRt7kEdHQAO7%20YIRIHFoQqBw18cyJaBGp6dAAgkRE3KiFxSAC2eXsaxDARcjINIRt0ADCIKR8O6jTzEfI47hZ6NAAvNCnfZmCmHuuXyGyKJTKADJlqt1ptDEDVDZmIh3hAAHRcXj8d4qABEB2eJzOrVxel%20VxudxxuLRtNxNjs0Bc-VIHEkMHkQSiM1AkBgAGUfIgAPIBCLXPkYQVVQIhMSEZAkaFrUFbBF7NjPcYcIy0VkqOwsRyOLWoN4Ar4-RB-IFSoXVOVQlYquHbVGI3qOFEAjE8KmCPEE46nWgksnWim3bEBml0hnQXpxOJAA)